# Followup on a closed question

Tags: support

Concerning [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1360747/dns-block-list-management) by [this user](https://superuser.com/users/947170/linux54):
The author's intent, to ask in order to find a solution for his problem, was a good one/idea. Actually it was a very good one, since doing usability research in this case asking the users currently should the preferred method for SW-engineers in writing "good" software (and here we finally a programmer who cares about the needs of the user in order to make a good product - even self motivated!). But the question was not appropriate to solve that problem and got deleted for good reasons.

I would like to feedback a better question to the author (since I have a very good idea how to solve his problem), but since the question is deleted I can't do that directly through a comment. Is there another way?

Here's google's cached page for the question, if you can't see deleted page: [Google cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:xu5bC-ZWDw4J:https://superuser.com/questions/1360747/dns-block-list-management%20&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de&client=firefox-b-ab)

Comment: What you are asking for breaches the user's privacy.

Comment: @Burgi sorry, my question get's perceived this way, and I don't know where you read that between the lines but that is definitely not what I'm asking for!! I would like to answer the users question or at least comment on it. I think it would benefit him as well as anyone how will use "his software" in the future. Theoretically if I could comment on a deleted question: of course it wouldn't be visible to anyone else but to the author since he will still be able to see his deleted question and all comments. It might still benefit him.

Answer (score 4):

If the user is active on chat or has other contact details on their profile, you can reach out to them. Alternatively, you can ask a question of your own and answer it.

The user in question appears to be new to the site and has no details filled in profile, so I dunno how you'd go about reaching out to them.

Comment: Those options I checked, sorry didn't bother to mention that in my question.

Comment: @Albin Well then, what else can you possibly do??

Comment: Not sure why you are asking me since that's exactly what my original question is?! But thanks for your suggestions anyway! I appreciate any input!

Comment: @Albin Unlike other forums, SE sites do not allow you to message a user directly. You can message them in chat if they're interested, or contact them by any means listed in their profile. But if they're not active on chat and if they don't have anything in their profile, there's nothing that we can possibly do.

Comment: I don't think the user will get a notification if I address them in a chat, will they?

Comment: @Albin Yes they will not, unless they've been active in the chat room in the past 7 days, and they don't have enough rep for chat anyway.

Comment: ah, ok, so this won't be possible. I'll wait, maybe some will think of a different solution or workaround (without breaching privacy of course).

Comment: @Albin, if they had posted any other question or answer (which their profile indicates they haven't), you could leave a comment to them on that post.

Answer (score 3):

> But the question was not appropriate to solve that problem and got
>   deleted for good reasons.

The question was deleted by the author not the community.  The author could have addressed the issues with the question, and would have recieved an answer to their question, which could still happen provided they ask a single question instead of four.  However, none of the questions they have asked in the current revision, are not within scope here at Superuser.  We must remember background context of those four questions, they are working to develope a SaaS for their company, and the author is seeking our feedback to those questions for them.

[image]

[image]

> The author's intent, to ask in order to find a solution for his problem, was a good one/idea.

After the question was improved, the author never indicated, what problem they were attempting to solve.  At one point the author asked, **"Would a service like this be of use and does it solve any potential problems that the superuser community may have?"**, which also wasn't appropriate for our community.

Additionally, the last revision by the author was simply seeking answers to questions, in order to develop their SaaS (Software as a service) which wasn't an apprpriate question for Superuser.  **The author didn't actually have a problem to solve, they were seeking our feedback, to develope their SaaS (Software as a service).**

> I would like to feedback a better question to the author (since I have a very good idea how to solve his problem), but since the question is deleted I can't do that directly through a comment.

If they are seeking our input to **develop their SaaS**, their question should remain deleted, since that isn't something we will provide.  The question should remain deleted if that is the case.  *While the user is registered, we are not a discussion forum, so there is no way to contact the author.*

> Actually it was a very good one, since doing usability research in this case asking the users currently should the preferred method for SW-engineers in writing "good" software (and here we finally a programmer who cares about the needs of the user in order to make a good product - even self motivated!).

What you describe is entirely out of scope here at Superuser.  I would go as far to say, there is not a single SE community, where it would be within scope.  **Stack Exchange communities are not discussion forums, it is inappropriate to use any SE community, to collect research to develope a software product.**

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood me. I never tried to make a point that that the question wasn't worth to be deleted, I even said so in my question. The problem the author had was he wanted to do user research but this was not the way. It was neither the right community nor the right question approach hat a good intend. I just wanted to leave a comment in point him in the right direction, that's it...  I suppose he deleted the question due to bad scores but anyway, I didn't intend to press the issue, I was just wanted to know if there's a way to give him feedback...

Comment: @Albin - There is not misunderstanding.  However, you indicated that you thought the question could be improved, and that simply is not the case.  The question was out of scope, and despite efforts to improve it, it remained out of scope.  **The question received zero votes, the author deleted it, for an unknown reason.**

Comment: no the question couldn't be improved it rather needs to address the actual problem, it had to be asked a completely different way to address his actual problem and not in this community either.

Comment: The user cannot be contacted, their question isn't appropriate for the SE community, our involvement should end at that point.  The author performed the proper action in the end by removing their question.

Comment: thx ramhound for you're explanation...  I'll just wait then, maybe some has a different solution for my "problem" (besides "contacting" him) - or it stays unsolved...